# Spotify SDK throwing "this._streamer is null" error when trying to play or skip audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I'm building an application that aims to take advantage of Spotify's web player SDK and allow playback. I have successfully connected user accounts to the player and all of the other required prerequisites, but whenever I try to play the audio (following Spotify's own example code), I receive a console error indicating:

Console errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._streamer is null
```

Edit: I would've posted the rest of the error stack, but the Spotify API URLs contained in them flagged the post as spam, so unfortunately they've been removed.

At the moment, the React component that this is coded within is a bit long, but I will remove irrelevant portions that relate to something else I'm trying to do:

App.js

```
// External imports
import { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

export default function CartPlayer(props) {

    const track = {
        name: "",
        album: {
            images: [
                { url: "" }
            ]
        },
        artists: [
            { name: "" }
        ]
    }

    const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
    const [isPlaybackActive, setIsPlaybackActive] = useState(false);
    const [currentTrack, setCurrentTrack] = useState(track);
    const [deviceId, setDeviceId] = useState(null);

    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();

    const spotifyAccessToken = cookies.userSpotifyAuth.access_token;

    // Spotify SDK hook
    useEffect(() => {

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
    
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    
        window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
    
            const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
                name: 'Web Playback SDK',
                getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(spotifyAccessToken); },
                volume: 0.5
            });

            setPlayer(player);

            player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
                console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
                setDeviceId(device_id);
            });
    
            player.addListener('not_ready', ({ device_id }) => {
                console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
            });
    
            player.addListener('player_state_changed', ( state => {

                if (!state) {
                    return;
                }

                setCurrentTrack(state.track_window.current_track);
                setIsPaused(state.paused);

                player.getCurrentState().then( state => { 
                    (!state)? setIsPlaybackActive(false) : setIsPlaybackActive(true) 
                });

            }));

            player.on('playback_error', ({message}) => {
                console.error('Failed to perform playback', message);
            })

            player.connect();
    
        };

    }, []);

        // This function transfers active playback to the Spotify session in the browser
    useEffect(() => {

        async function transferPlayback() {

            await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player', {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookies.userSpotifyAuth.access_token
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    device_ids: [
                        deviceId
                    ],
                    play: true
                })
            });

        }

        if (deviceId) {
            transferPlayback();
        }

    }, [deviceId])

    if (!isPlaybackActive) { 
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="main-wrapper">
                        <b> Instance not active. Transfer your playback using your Spotify app </b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>)
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="main-wrapper">

                        <img src={currentTrack.album.images[0].url} className="now-playing__cover" alt="" />

                        <div className="now-playing__side">
                            <div className="now-playing__name">{currentTrack.name}</div>
                            <div className="now-playing__artist">{currentTrack.artists[0].name}</div>

                            <button className="btn-spotify" onClick={() => { player.previousTrack() }} >
                                &lt;&lt;
                            </button>

                            <button className="btn-spotify" onClick={() => { player.togglePlay() }} >
                                { isPaused ? "PLAY" : "PAUSE" }
                            </button>

                            <button className="btn-spotify" onClick={() => { player.nextTrack() }} >
                                &gt;&gt;
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
```

The code is very similar to what Spotify provides as an example, save for a function that's called whenever the in-browser "device" is ready and gains an ID, then requesting an active state for itself so that it can actively play audio. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: With all due respect, this is the minimal reproducible example. I removed about 60% that was my own implementation, and this is a near duplicate of Spotify's own example code available at https://github.com/spotify/spotify-web-playback-sdk-example/blob/main/src/WebPlayback.jsx, which I tried to merely copy into my application and received the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround/solution. the issue seems to be with React 18, something is messing up with the `iframe` called from the SDK.

My solution was to downgrade to react 17 and it then worked like a charm. I have a private repo so I can't share but please share you react version if it's not 18.

If you are like me and you used Next.js, this is how to downgrade https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36006

Comment: I'm sorry, I never came back to respond to my own post, but reached a similar solution after digging through Spotify's developer community forum. Good to know that it has to do with the SDK's iframe call, thanks for that insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question was asked, but I recently ran into this issue on Next.js 14 + React 18 and had to fix it myself so I thought I'd share my solution.

I noticed also there were a problem with iframes, and possibly specifically with how React 18 is using `createRoot` now, so I started experimenting. It seems that using a component like such inside your main components to load the Spotify SDK will work:

```
import { type FC, createElement } from 'react';

const SpotifyScript: FC = () => {
  const script = createElement('script', {
    id: 'spotify-player',
    type: 'text/javascript',
    async: false,
    defer: true,
    src: 'https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js',
    onLoad: () => {
      console.log('Spotify loaded');
    },
    onError: console.error
  });

  return script;
};

export default SpotifyScript;
```

Not sure exactly what the reason is, but I have tested this, and it atleast gets me past errors with calling `player.getCurrentState()` and such. You can still use the `window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady` callback to create your player and save it to some state.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would upvote, but alas, I do not have enough reputation